# Javascript onclick event out of phase in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, onclick

Using Angular framework to build my website's front-end, I'm trying to include a button/icon capable of opening and closing this sidenav:

```
<nav id="left-sidenav" class="sidenav">
<div class="local_nav">
    <a class="link" href="#">About</a>
    <a class="link" href="#">Services</a>
    <a class="link" href="#">Clients</a>
    <a class="link" href="#">Contact</a>
</div>
</nav>
```

I found a cool [hamburger fold-out menu](https://codepen.io/erikterwan/pen/EVzeRP) on codepen.io, and I ended up modelling the HTML code this way.

```
<div id="menuToggle">
<input type="checkbox" onclick="toggleNav()" />
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<ul id="menu"></ul>
</div>
```

With this being the toggleNav() function (added to index.html head):

```
<script>
    //sidenav-width: 150px (this is defined in sidenav.component.scss)
    function toggleNav() {
        var x = document.getElementById("left-sidenav");
        if (x.style.width === "0px") {
            //openNav
            x.style.width = "150px";
        } else {
            //closeNav
            x.style.width = "0px";
        }
    }
</script>
```

So when the page is loaded, it looks like this [please don't mind the image, it's my first time using Angular and I'm trying to get better :) ]:
[Reloaded page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXoJf.png)

Now, for some reason, when trying to use this burger menu the first click doesn't trigger the onclick event, and the icon ends up transforming (as it should do) in a cross (see the codepen.io CSS).
[Page after the first click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8F3aZ.png)

On the second click though, the event seems to start working and the sidenav finally shows up, with the cross reverting into the burger icon. If I keep clicking on the burger, it just works as it should, with the icon being out of phase.
[Page after the second click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QBri.png);
[Page after the third click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8F3aZ.png)

This makes no sense to me, and I initially wanted to get the cross when the sidenav is **shown**, not when it's hidden.
Does anyone know how to actually fix this?

Comment: Why are you using a `<script>` in `index.html` to handle component's behavior ? Have you followed first steps on getting started with Angular ? Can you please reproduce your code on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rz2xvk) ? I'll be glad to help you update a stackblitz.

Comment: Don't use script tag, if you are using angular then use a service to handle this.

Comment: @Florian Sure, I'll try my best to add all the code on stackblitz. I thought it would have been easier to add and handle all the Js scripts on the head of the index, but I also tried to add them in the HTML files as scripts and nothing changes. Should I generate a different .js file to paste the code in?

Comment: @cloned what do you mean by service?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services if you search for angular and service you will find a ton of examples. This would be the angular way to solve your problem.

Comment: You don't need a service, you need a component. This component will handle the logic to toggle your menu.

Comment: @Florian https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-1iapoh?file=src/app/app.component.ts Here's the code I uploaded on Stackblitz, I would be pleased if you decided to help me on my project.

Comment: @nicocardo__ `NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'write$1' on null` the stackblitz you provided give me this error

Comment: @Florian I've been looking for a solution to this problem in the last few days, and since I've never used Stackblitz before I couldn't figure it out. I've made my research and it seems I'm not the only one who got this situation; I'm pretty sure asking another question on https://stackoverflow.com/ would be the right way to approach this mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been struggling with this for 6 days now but I finally solved the problem just by changing the JS code this way:

```
<script>
    //sidenav-width: 150px        
    var open = false;

    function toggleNav() {
        let x = document.getElementById("left-sidenav");
        if (open == false) {
            //openNav
            x.style.width = "150px";
        }
        if (open == true) {
            //closeNav
            x.style.width = "0px";
        }
        open = !open;
    }
</script>
```

It's not the most correct way to handle this in Angular, but it works.
Let me know if you found this helpful or if there's a more proper way to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the implementation of the function `toggleNav()` for this:

In your .ts file add this.

```
toggle: boolean = false;

toggleNav() {
    this.toggle = !this.toggle;
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }
```

Comment: I tried to add your code into my app.component.ts file, but it seems to reject it; how do you suggest I should implement it into my project? Could you specify how and where to actually add the code? Thanks :)

Comment: You can add my code in your app.component.ts. In the ts file that has your toggle. Send me the exact error to read it

Comment: I'll paste in my next comment the output of the VSCode node terminal when I try to compile the local server with your code in my app.component.ts file. I'll have to delete some lines of code since comments are restricted to a max length of 600 characters.

Comment: Error: src/app/app.component.ts:10:9 - error: 'boolean' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
10 toggle: boolean = false;
Error: src/app/app.component.ts:12:1 - error: Cannot find name 'toggleNav'.
12 toggleNav() {
Error: src/app/app.component.ts:12:13 - error: ';' expected.
12 toggleNav() {
Error: src/app/app.component.ts:13:5 - error: Object is possibly 'undefined'.
13     this.toggle = !this.toggle;
Error: src/app/app.component.ts:13:20 - error: Object is possibly 'undefined'.
13     this.toggle = !this.toggle;
× Failed to compile.